# Android Studio - "No analysis has been performed"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, code-analysis

[image]

I'm having this weird problem.  Code analysis and errors are not showing within a particular file, but they work fine in other files.  The icon "OFF" appears where the green check-mark should be.

I checked power save mode, it's disabled.

How do I turn code analysis back on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem. Look in the **lower-right corner** of the window for the sad-policeman icon. It's for setting the "Current Inspection Profile".

[image]

Comment: Had this problem in Pycharm on a JavaScript file outside my normal development directories. @Basheer I couldn't find the icon at first. Hope you like my editing.